# Horizontal lines appear to be wavy when scrolling on rotated IPS monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, lag

I am connecting an Acer (CB271HU bmidprx 27” IPS 2K) monitor connected via DisplayPort to my 13'' 2017 MBP (graphics card: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB). When I turn the monitor in portrait (90deg rotation), I notice lines don't update at the same rate horizontally. They appear to be wavy when I scroll up and down. I recorded the screen when I scroll through a picture [here](https://youtu.be/AJNGAROZ0p8). It appears that the left half of the rotated screen is lagging behind the right half. Is this normal or how should I fix this?

Comment: And your question is? Also, you may want to advise the OS.